# Action de Web APi 2 retorna un json vacio

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-web-api

Tengo el siguiente action que está devolviendo un Ilist, al momento de de devolver datos resulta un Json Vacío:

```
[
    {}
]
```

el método del apicontroller esta asi;

```
[HttpGet]
public IHttpActionResult ConsultaPuertos([FromUri] string id, 
[FromBody] List<PuertosGP> lstPuertosGP, [FromUri] DateTime fecha)
{

     var resultList1 = puertosGPRepository.ConsultaPuertos(id, lstPuertosGP, 
    fecha);
  return Ok(resultList1); 
 });
```

Es factible enviar un Json(resultList1)? o hacer de la acción no devolviendo un IList sino un JsonResult?

**UPDATE** En el paso a paso se observa que al menos un registro retorna del puertosGPRepository(...) [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

en el POSTMAN sale vacio el json

**UPDATE 2**

he cambiado en mi WebApiConfig.cs

tengo esta linea:

```
    public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        // Configuración y servicios de API web
        // Web API configuration and services
        config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Add(new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json"));//text/html
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Prueba `var jsonData = JSON.FromJSONString<List<PuertosGP>>(resultList1);
`

Comment: @David no funcionó., segun esto se debe colocar un JsonResult en vez de public async Task<IList<PuertosGP>> osea public async Task<IList<PuertosGP>> ????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Antes que nada el método tiene que ser *GET*, ya que estas realizando una consulta/petición, los métodos *POST* son para publicar/guardar información. Es decir, cambiar `[HttpPost]` por `[HttpGet]`, además te falta colocar el **await** en la consulta realizada en resultList1, ya que definiste el método como **async**, es decir te quedará.

```
var resultList1 = await puertosGPRepository.ConsultaPuertos(id, lstPuertosGP, fecha).ToListAsynchronous();
```

Generalmente en los API se utilizan los métodos **IHttpActionResult** ya que te permiten devolver un `return Content` con más especificaciones de la consulta, te recomiendo también cambiar la firma del método `Task<IList<PuertosGP>>` por `Task<List<PuertosGP>>`.

Comment: el resultlist1 es de tipo List<>esa linea al agregar ToListArray sale error 
"List<PuertosGP>" no contiene una definición para ToListAsynchronous ni se encuentra ningún método de extensión "ToListAsynchronous" accesible que acepte un primer argumento del tipo List<PuertosGP> falta alguna directiva using o una referencia de ensamblado? ni ToListAsync() no utilizo EF,  Es un proyecto que estoy retomando, que quedarían los metodos asi?: [HttpGet]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> ConsultaPuertos([FromUri] string id, 
[FromBody] List<PuertosGP> lstPuertosGP, [FromUri] DateTime fecha)

Comment: Ah ok, te quedaría de la siguiente manera:


`[HttpGet]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> ConsultaPuertos([FromUri] string id, [FromBody] List<PuertosGP> lstPuertosGP, [FromUri] DateTime fecha)
{

  var resultList1 = await puertosGPRepository.ConsultaPuertos(id, lstPuertosGP, fecha);

  return Ok(resultList1); 
}`